# Excel VBA runtime error '1004'

Tags: excel, vba

I'm assuming that this question has been asked many a-time, but hopefully mine is a bit different.

I'm having issues correcting a 1004 runtime error. I've tried moving the code to and from module to worksheet, neither changed anything. I cannot really see how I'm meant to rephrase the loop which it is apparently failing at

```
Sub ProgramHideCycle()

Dim PROGGRAPH As Worksheet
Dim Project As Excel.Workbook
Dim Cell As Range
Dim CharPos(1 To 3) As Integer
Dim ValueENERGCount As Integer
Dim ValueCONSUCount As Integer
Dim ValueCONTRCount As Integer

ValueENERGCount = 0
ValueCONSUCount = 0
ValueCONTRCount = 0

Set Project = ThisWorkbook

With Project

Set PROGGRAPH = .Sheets("Program Graph")

For Each Cell In PROGGRAPH.Range(A5, A93)

CharPos(1) = InStr(1, Cell.Value, "ENERG")
CharPos(2) = InStr(1, Cell.Value, "CONTR")
CharPos(3) = InStr(1, Cell.Value, "CONSU")

If CharPos(1) < 0 Then
    ValueENERGCount = 1
ElseIf CharPos(2) < 0 Then
    ValueCONTRCount = 1
ElseIf CharPos(3) < 0 Then
    ValueCONSUCount = 1
Else
    Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = (Cell.Value = 0 Or Cell.Value = "")
End If

Next Cell
End With
End Sub
```

The code apparently fails at the beginning of the 'for' loop, yet attempting to change that doesn't seem to do anything. I'm likely missing something glaringly obvious, thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: you don't need to set the `sheet` when the code is already running within the worksheet. The for-loop would be `for each cell in range("A5", "A93")`

Comment: Is there any way that I could clean this up? It's pretty sloppy right now but doesn't seem to work the way I anticipated it to, either. I'm trying to get it so that when it sees a cell with, "ENERG", for example, then it hides anything else with that part of the naming convention to only display one version of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
PROGGRAPH.Range("A5", "A93")
```

Comment: Wow, I'm actually that bad and managed to miss something as basic as syntax. Good God, thanks for the help, though.

Comment: @TheMemeTeam There are other probably coding errors also.  For example, `Instr` won't return a value less than `0`

Comment: I know that. I'm mainly looking for when InStr produces a value that isn't zero. I tried using '<>' but that doesn't seem to change anything either.

Comment: @TheMemeTeam Yes, but none of your `IF ...ELSEIF` statements will ever return `TRUE`.  If `<> 0`  (or `>0`) always fails, then there is no match

Comment: I didn't know that the IF ... ELSEIF would never return true. From what I can tell, they produce integers and don't act as Booleans, nor does InStr if I'm right

Comment: @TheMemeTeam Sloppy phrasing on my part.  I should have written that the **conditions** being tested by your `IF` will never return `TRUE`

Comment: Alright, I've changed some things and am now hitting runtime error '13'. Great fun >.>

Comment: @TheMemeTeam Since my response apparently answered your original question, I suggest you mark this as answered, and then, after going as far as you can with debugging, post your modified code and problems as a new question.  Also be sure to provide examples of data and what you expect for results.